# Ruby で MongoDB から特定のフィールドのみを取得したい

Tags: ruby, mongodb

RubyでMongoDBの特定のフィールド(カラム)のみを取得したいのですが、全てのフィールドが取得されてしまい、理想通りの結果が得られません。

findメソッドの指定の仕方はリファレンス通りですが、取り出し方が悪いのでしょうか？
ご教授いだたけると幸いです。

MongoDBバージョン 4.4.1

理想の結果

```rb
{title: '記事のタイトル'}
```

実際の結果

```rb
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('xxx'), title: '記事のタイトル', content: '記事の中身' }
```

メソッド

```rb
db = Mongo::Client.new([ 'mongodb' ], client_data)
collection = db[:post].find({}, { title: 1 })
# collection = db[:post].find({}, { _id: 0, title: 1, content: 0 }) # 全てのフィールドに0・1を指定しても同様の結果
collection.each do |val|
    p val
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find({}, {title: 1})`はmongoコマンドでの書き方ですね。

[Ruby用ドライバの説明](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-projections/)を見ると、
`find({}, {'projection'=>{'title'=>1}})` と書けば良さそうです。

ただし上のようにすると`title`だけでなく`_id`も返されます。
`_id`フィールドは指定に含めなくても返され、含まないようにするには除外指定が必要です。
つまり`_id`も除外して`title`だけを得るには
`find({}, {'projection'=>{'title'=>1, '_id'=>0}})`
とすることになります。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。理想通りの結果になりました。